# How do I match a data set with missing dates to a column of complete dates?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello and good afternoon, I am trying to match a data set of historical stock prices at open, high, low, and close to a list of dates.

I have the full list of dates spanning from 1/22/20 to 7/6/22, but the stock price data of course does not include dates of weekends or holidays, which are included in my original full list of dates.

I am compilling a data set that includes many other variables that have values recorded on these weekend and holiday dates, so those dates do prove crucial.

[This image shows the stock price data I would like to match to the full list of dates, as one could see there are dates missing, given weekends and holidays. This goes all the way down to row #621](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nQV1.png)

[This image shows the full list of dates that I would like to match the stock price data to. This goes all the way down to row #899](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKrvP.png)

Thank you so much for your help, and please forgive me if there are any errors in my question.

[This is a picture for a comment dialogue between @P.b. and I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFZTv.png)

[This is a second picture for a comment dialogue between @P.b. and I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXkMk.png)

Comment: So what do you expect? Can you provide an example of data you expect as a result?

Comment: Hello @P.b., the stock price data would go to its corresponding date on the full list of dates. Of course, weekends and holidays would remain blank. I could do this manually, but given that I have many more ticker symbols with long time horizons, it would save me a lot of time.

Comment: INDEX with MATCH, VLOOKUP, XLOOKUP, FILTER, all mentioned can achieve what you want.

Comment: Hello @P.b., thank you for your reply. Would it be possible if you could give an example of how to format the function?

Comment: `=IFERROR(INDEX($BY$3:$CB$621,MATCH($A$2:$A$899,$BX$3:$BX$621,0),MATCH($B$2:$E$2,$BX$2:$CB$2,0)),"")` (untested)

Comment: Hello @P.b, you are a life saver. The only thing is that it doesnt seem to show the CB stock price close values column, but it shows the rest. I will add a screenshot via edit to my question so you can see.

Comment: My apologies, it is showing the CB stock price close values column but it is not showing the BY stock price open values column.

Comment: Hey P.b., do you know if there is a way to get rid of the top row of cells, so that I can align the dates correctly. I tried a couple different ways but they dont seem to be working. I will put a new photo in a question edit

Comment: `=IFERROR(INDEX($BY$3:$CB$621,MATCH($A$3:$A$899,$BX$3:$BX$621,0),MATCH($B$2:$E$2,$BY$2:$CB$2,0)),"")` and paste it in B3. I started at the wrong row.